# UWP Prism App crashes when sideloaded next to another sideloaded Prism App

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app, prism

The title tells it already:

I have 2 Windows Apps (both relying on Micorosft.Prism), which I want to sideload on a win 8.1 computer.

Each App works perfectly fine if installed over the appstore, or if I just install one of these apps.

If I sideload both apps, the second app crashes on startup (Prism.MVVM crashes) - the first app still works fine.
If I de-install the second app, and sideload it again - both apps work fine...

Since my client wants to sideload both apps on several employee machines, this is a serious problem.

Has anyone a tip?

**EDIT:**

This is also the case if I try to sideload 2 empty prism apps - so it's definitly the prism library

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using Prism in your apps that is not matter, prism is just a MVVM framework.
I installed 5 o 6 sideload apps using prism without problems it seems your problem could be the manifest and the SID of your apps please check the value of the SID of your apps they can't be the same and they can't have the same name and App Store association.

Best regards